# Ionic 3 Leaflet change icon marker

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet

I want to change the icon marker in ionic 3,

```
var dot= L.icon({
iconUrl: 'dot.png',
shadowUrl: 'dot-shadow.png',
iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
shadowSize: [50, 64], // size of the shadow
iconAnchor: [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's 
shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative..
});
...
...
L.marker([this.lat, this.lng], { icon: dot}).addTo(this.map);
```

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon

It is not working! just does not show ther marker, there is not show any error.
Where must to be the dot.png?

Comment: where is the file called dot.png?

Comment: `iconUrl` is an absolute URL or a relative (to the script being executed) URL. So your `dot.png` should be in the same directory as the script.

Comment: I try to put in the same directory and iconUrl: '../assets/dot.png', but I have the same issue.

Comment: In web app work but in android app does´t work